# How to trim folder names by using cmd command in windows

Tags: cmd.exe

I would like to trim folder names by using cmd command like below.
Is it possible? Thank you!
(I tried.. like this in cmd : `for %i in (*) do ren "%i" "???"`)

Folder names

29155 -> 291

99911 -> 999

33002 -> 330

Comment: Its not command line but there's a really good windows powertoys tool called power rename that's great for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this `.bat` file (assumed to be within this parent folder) :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /d %%i in (*) do (
  set "x=%%i"
  echo "%%i" "!x:~0,3!"
  ren "%%i" "!x:~0,3!"
)
```

References :

- [FOR /D](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)
- [EnableDelayedExpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: WOW!! it works!! thanx!!